# EGit - using different pull strategies

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'd like to use different pull strategies at different times.  My goal is a linear history on each individual branch, but a merge that preserves history when merging branches together.

If I'm pulling from the same branch (for instance, local=master, pull from remote=origin/master) I'd like to do a rebase.

When I'm pulling from a *different* branch (local=master, remote=origin/featurebranch) I'd like to do a merge.

What's the best way to set up EGit to do this with the fewest clicks and least confusion?

In other words, I'm looking for a one-click `git pull --rebase` with the option to do a `git pull origin [branch or pull request]`.

This would be straightforward from the command line but I'm not sure how to do it in EGit.
I'm not sure the checkbox for pull strategy on a per-branch basis is the best way to do this, because I feel like the pull strategy is tied to the activity rather than the branch itself.